# How to make Jquery object start to bounce when scrolling to it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, scroll, bounce

I have a website with 1 page.

The page width is 17289px.

It is divided to separated pages each page width 1920px.
So there is only a horizontal scrolling
On page 8 I have an image.
I what to make the image bounce once only when the user scrolls to this page.
If the user out of this page it will stop bouncing.

this is my code now:

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) { 
    if($(window).scrollLeft() > 1920*6 && $(window).scrollLeft() < 1920*7) {
        $("#astronaut").effect("bounce", { distance:400 }, 1600);
    }
});
```

Now what happens is that when the user scrolls to the page the image bounces all the time and doesn't stop ever.

Can someone help here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just have it bounce `n` number of times?  Just add the `times` attribute to your bounce effect to define the number of times the element will bounce.  Set it to whatever integer number you like. I have set it to 10 times in this example:

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) { 
    if($(window).scrollLeft() > 1920*6 && $(window).scrollLeft() < 1920*7) {
        $("#astronaut").effect("bounce", { distance:400, times:10 }, 1600);
    }
});
```

Once the element bounces `n` number of times it will stop.

Comment: It doesn't stop because the event $(window).scroll is looping it

Comment: It will stop until you scroll again. What behavior are you wanting?

Comment: some ting like this

var counter = 0;
$(window).scroll(function (event) { 
 
 getPageDataByScrollPosition();

 if($(window).scrollLeft()>1920*6 && $(window).scrollLeft()<1920*7){
  if (counter==0){
   $("#astronaut").effect("bounce", {distance:400}, 1600);
   counter = 1;
  }
 }
 else{
  counter = 0;
 }
});